# Compilation Error when editing Strings.resx file in Hangfire.Core v1.7.18

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hangfire

Can someone help me resolve this error? I downloaded the Hangfire v1.7.18 from GitHub and I get the following error when I add/edit a key/value in the Strings.resx file.

The error is thrown on line 42 and specifically on this part - typeof(Strings).Assembly
and it looks like it is happening for .netstandard 1.3. Here is the complete error:

```
Error|CS1061| ‘Type’ does not contain a definition for ‘Assembly’ and no accessible extension method ‘Assembly’ accepting a first argument of type ‘Type’ could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in Project Hangfire.Core (netstandard1.3) The file is src\Hangfire.Core\Dashboard\Content\resx\Strings.Designer.cs at Line 42
```